# Add slash to string

Tags: c#, string

I want to replace such string

```
'10001'
```

into

```
\'10001\'
```

The following code doesnt work:

```
Console.WriteLine(content);
content.Replace("'", "\\'");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

or even this:

```
Console.WriteLine(content);
content.Replace("'", "\\\\'");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

The value `content` is exactly the same before and after `replace`, i.e. `'10001'`

I'm using VC# 2010 Express. Thanks for help.

Comment: replace does not change content object. it returns new value. strings are immutable in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write:

```
content = content.Replace("'", "\\'");
```

`string` is an immutable type, which means it can't be modified. Instead the methods like `Replace`, `Insert`, etc. always return a new string instance. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx#Immutability) for more information.

BTW: if you're using ReSharper (or maybe a similar tool), it will warn you when you call `string.Replace()` without assigning/using the method's return value.

Comment: @Akari: No problem! In fact, I also made that same mistake in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

`content = content.Replace("'", "\\\\'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
content = content.Replace("'", "\\'")
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to output json string? looks like you are attempting to do that. If that's the case you can json serializer to serialize normal string to json string just like the one  that you asked for.